# What is this doorbell sound on notifications (ONYX Lineage14.1-20170420)

Tags: notifications, lineageos, 7.1-nougat, oneplus-x

When I receive a notification on my phone, it plays a long doorbell sound (regardless of which app causes the notification). Where does it come from and how do I disable it? I can't find it in Sound or Notification options.

I recorded the sound in a video from my other phone, here is a link to it:
https://youtu.be/O4brgMjAS3M

Furthermore, last time I wanted to authenticate with google 2 step verification, the sound kept playing until i rebooted my phone (latest gapps installed - mini 20170427)

Comment: This tune is definitely "Argon" from the alarms ringtone. Check your alarm settings.

Comment: Thanks Andy, you pointed me to what is apparently a glitch in the OS. The tune for notifications was indeed set to Argon, however, when I selected Argon from the list of tunes, another tune was played than the one in my youtube movie. So I thought that couldn't be the setting causing this sound. Also, while the main sounds menu showed "Argon", when I clicked the setting to change the tune, no tune was selected in the list (So the Argon radiobutton in the tune list was blank, while the menu showed Argon was selected). I've now set it to "None" and the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: That sounds quite messed up. I have a handful of LOS14.1 devices and none of them seem to have this issue, though. Might wanna wait for a newer version of the ROM?

Comment: Now that I've selected the "None" option, the choice is in fact checked in the "None"-radiobutton when I re-open the tune picker. I cannot revert to the faulty state with the radiobutton not being checked. That's because the tune radiobutton picker does work properly. I suspect during installation or a previous upgrade, the configured tune somehow became set to an option which did not appear in the radiobutton list. (In other words, the choices for a tune changed after an upgrade, while the stored choice was still set to a deprecated tune)